# pdsh can't find identity file, but ssh can. why?

Tags: ssh

When I ssh with:

```
ssh -i'/tmp/my-identity-file' -l'root' ip-address
```

I am able to ssh to my destination host without issue. I'd like to use `pdsh` to do a similar thing, so my command is:

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-i'/tmp/my-identity-file" pdsh -l'root' ip-address
```

But, the output from `pdsh` is:

```
ip-address: Warning: Identity file '/tmp/my-identity-file not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I changed the permissions on the identity file to be `0666` just for testing, but continue getting the same result. It seems to me that `pdsh` is not passing the `PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND` on to `ssh` as I would expect. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Looks like too many quotes in there.  That single quote is being interpreted as part of the filename.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I mistyped the error here. The actual error had a single quote on either side of the file name. But, your comment got me to look into the quoting in my script and I did have one too many pairs of single quotes around the file name. thanks!